Precise meaning of "я прошла мимо этого дома"?
Does it mean I walked past this house or I missed this house?

It depends on the context. Without one both variants are possible. Could you please provide the context?


Я опоздала на встречу, потому что прошла мимо этого дома

In this example the meaning is "I was late to the meeting because I missed this house".

Когда я шла на работу, я прошла мимо этого дома

In this example the meaning is "When I was going to work I walked past this house"
